# Why does the Bloomberg API occasionally hang on certain commands?

Tags: bloomberg

I'm subscribing to live data with the Bloomberg API. Occasionally, it hangs on the call to `session.Cancel(correlationID)`

1. Anyone know why?
2. Where can I find documentation on the API?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about the .NET or Java API.  In either case you should be able to find documentation (pdfs) by running WAPI on a Bloomberg terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The Bloomberg API can be run in two modes - synchronous and asynchronous. So if you've taken some code example using `WAPI` and it happens to have been synchronous, you will face delays in your application.

The mode differs in the way data is accessed, for e.g.

1. the COM API in asynchronous mode would first send out the request using one procedure and another procedure is called back to execute when the data is fetched and ready, hence enabling the user to continue interacting with the GUI.
2. The synchronous mode would handle data requests and fetching in the same function with the same thread causing the app to hang. It won't make a big difference for the single value return types, but some large data sets could cause delays depending on your leased-line or internet bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question referring to the Bloomberg's Excel Add-In or its API Library releases to access live dataI? In either case, unless the data is not widely available to the public, and unless you have a special subscription arrangement from Bloomberg or other data feeds that can be sourced through the terminal, you are going to run into limits on the amount of live data that you are able to gather in any single interval.

To answer your second question, you can access [Documentation for Bloomberg's Developers API](http://www.bbhub.io/labs/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf) here. And you can find Documentation and Resources for [Bloomberg's API Libraries / Releases](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/) here.